# Remove notification ongoing

Tags: android

I'm building a music player for android. When running in background I want to disable swipe on notification as long as music is playing but when user pauses music swipe should be enabled.

I tried updating `setOnGoing(false)` from `setOnGoing(true)` on Notification builder when music is paused but it doesn't seem to work. It's still not enabling swipe on notification.

```
Notification notification = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_icon)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
                .build();
```

on pausing play this is executed:

```
Notification notif = mBuilder.setOngoing(false).build();
        notif.bigContentView = mRemoteViews;
        notif.contentView = mRemoteViewsCollapsed;
```

mBuilder is class level Notification.Builder

This updates the contentView properly but does not change its Ongoing state

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Flag

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.play_icon, whatever, when);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: I want it to become "not ongoing" when i pause playback

Comment: then why are you using `.setOngoing(true)`? try to use `.setOngoing(false)` when media player is paused

Comment: When I first create notification I setOngoing true but when user pause it I want it behave like setOnGoing false. Similar to how it works in Google play music player

Comment: i understand that see my 2nd comment does it help?

Comment: im already doing that. I figured out Swipe is disabled because I'm setting notification via startForeground of Service and that's why on setting setOngoing to false not having any effect.

Comment: also look into the priority too, try changing its priority too when player is paused

Answer (score 0):

I Tried it this way and it's working for me:

```
Notification notification = mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_icon)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .build();

//setOngoing after building
notification = builder.build();
    builder.setOngoing(true);
```

Player functions:

```
playerPause(){
    ...
    builder.setOngoing(false);
}
playerResume(){
    ...
    builder.setOngoing(true);
}
```